# How to create bubble chat TableViewCell like in Messenger using XCode's Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, xcode, chat, cell, messenger

I'm currently trying to implement a chat for my application but since I'm new at `Swift` development I got stuck at the part where I have to create the `TableView` cells for it. I was able to find 2 png images of "chat bubbles" (one for receiving and one for sending). 
I placed them in `Assets` and loaded them in an `ImageView`. Now my problem is how can I place a `Label` inside the `ImageView` and rescale it depending on how many lines of text are in the `Label`. The bubble should not exceed `66%` of the screen's width.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29482159/341994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there are a few considerations:

1. If you haven’t already, make your asset stretchable (where the corners aren’t stretched, but only the center is) by:

   - selecting the asset and zoom in so you can better refine the slices;
   - in the Xcode menu, choose “Editor” » “Show Slicing”;
   - click on “Start Slicing”:
     [image]
   - click on the center “horizontal and vertical stretching” button:
     [image]
   - move your guides to where you want them:
     [image]
   - now when you add the image view using this new stretchable asset and choose “Content Mode” of “Scale to Fit”, it will scale in such a way that the center is stretched but the edges aren’t:
     [image]

   Also see Xcode documentation [“Add a resizable area to an image”](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/deve65bd8d0d).
2. In your cell, now just add this image view and the label:

   - defining the label’s leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints to be inset from the edges of the image view;
   - define the label’s line count to zero;
   - define the image view’s width to be “>=” the container view width (with a multiplier of 66%);
   - obviously define your bubble’s appropriate leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints to its superview, too; and
   - make sure your cell is using automatic cell height.

For the sake of completeness, the other approach is to make an `@IBDesignable` view where you draw the bubble yourself with a `CAShapeLayer` whose `path` is the `cgPath` of a `UIBezierPath`. This is what I’ve done in my chat apps. But this stretchable image approach works fine, too.

By the way, if your speaker and listener bubbles are different colors, note that you might want to have flipped renditions of these bubbles for RTL languages.